# Увеличение дискового пространства

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня на одном жестком диске несколько разделов. Место в файловой системе на разделе с *Ubuntu* подходит к концу. Могу ли я как-то "перетащить" свободное пространство из одного раздела на другой?

Comment: да, создайте на разделе файловую систему, примонтируйте её куда-нибудь, и используйте для хранения файлов.

Comment: А как создается файловая система на разделе ?

Comment: как обычно: `$ sudo mkfs -t тип раздел`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ввиду того, что вопрос очень *общий*, а вариантов реализации несколько больше одного, я приведу лишь общее описание наиболее популярных вариантов, без детальных инструкций по реализации каждого из упомянутых вариантов.

1. вероятно, наилучший вариант, но вами, скорее всего, упущенный — использование [*lvm*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVM). если бы раздел, на котором находится используемая сейчас файловая система, во время установки был бы задействован как *логический том* (*logical volume*), то с помощью несложных манипуляций вы бы могли добавить любой (свободный) раздел диска (или даже диск целиком) в ту же группу томов (`pvcreate`+`vgextend`), увеличить размер тома (`lvextend`), а затем и размер файловой системы (`resize2fs`) прямо на работающей системе. инструкций по этому поводу — огромное количество. [например](http://www.o-nix.com/pages/reshenija-v-linux/rasshirenie-kornevogo-razdela-lvm.php).
2. для объединения файловых систем, располагающихся на разных разделах (одного и того же или даже разных дисков) можно воспользоваться возможностями программы *mhddfs* из одноимённого пакета. [пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/264853/).
3. ну и можно просто примонтировать (`mount`) файловую систему, созданную (`mkfs`) на разделе, в какое-нибудь подходящее место, и хранить там файлы.

   1. как «подвариант» стоит упомянуть и перенос содержимого какого-нибудь каталога (например, `/home`) в файловую систему, созданную на неиспользуемом разделе, с последующим авто-монтированием этой файловой системы в этот (ставший пустым после переноса) каталог. делается это обычно на нерабочей системе (т.е., надо загрузиться с какого-нибудь live-носителя, в качестве которого подойдёт, например, установочный диск любого популярного дистрибутива). хотя можно и «вживую»: [один из множества примеров](http://fixhead.blogspot.com/2014/09/home-ubuntu-1404.html).

Answer (score 1):

Можно изменить размеры разделов и файловых систем с помощью `gparted`. Чтобы иметь полные возможности по изменению раздела, требуется ФС отмонтировать, поэтому для изменения корневого раздела лучше загрузиться с live-USB, например с установочной ubuntu в режиме "без установки". Если к разделу с файловой системой ext4 добавляется пространство в конец, то ФС позволяет изменять свой размер на лету.

При добавлении пространства в начало раздела, gparted перемещает ФС на это количество блоков, а потом добавляет блоки в конец ФС. Тут следует проявить осторожность, если он является загрузочным: после всех изменений нужно будет переустановить загрузчик!