# Как расширить место внутри папки home имея другой физический диск?

Tags: ubuntu

Если у меня home смонтирована на диске ssd.
А еще есть hdd диск где объем больше. Можно как то расширить папку home за счёт этого?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583657/178576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примонтировать новый диск как каталог внутри /home
Позже прописать в /etc/fstab, чтобы диск автоматически подключался

Comment: А как это сделать? Можете привести пример если не сложно?

Comment: Подключаете диск, с помощью df находите файловую систему, с помощью blkid находите UUID, в /etc/fstab добавляете строчку 
UUID=%UUID диска%   %точка монтирования%   %тип фс%   defaults   0    2

Тип файловой системы так же будет в выдаче blkid