# Как перебросить часть места на диске в линуксе

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Ситуация в системе выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотелось бы перебросить часть свободного места с "/dev/md4" на "/dev/root", вопрос как это сделать, не затрагивая при этом данных.

Comment: не затрагивая данных, т.е. не перенося файлы, никак. Можно выбрать какую нибудь большую папку на корню, не требующуюся в процессе загрузки, перенести ее на md4 и сделать символическую ссылку на нее из того места где она раньше была

Comment: @Mike хорошая идея, спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583657/178576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Лучше перенести var.

Запускаешь через init=/bin/bash

```
. /etc/profile
mount -a
mv /var /home
ln -s /home/var /var
reboot
```

## Можно перенести 200Г без потерь на root.

Раздел root это скорее всего `/dev/md3` и располагается они между home и boot.

Переносится руками это просто (если не брать во внимание raid) но долго. Для конкретных команд нужно знать тип raid. Если lvm - то всё делается без переноса данных.

Первым делом срезаем хоум. Заодно он дефрагментируется. Может занять много времени.

```
resize2fs /dev/md4 200G
```

Потом уменьшаем размер раздела. Зависит от его типа.
Для mbr просто удаляем его и создаем с меньшим размером на том же месте.

Дальше на свободном месте создается новый раздел.

(для lvm не нужно) Туда копируем все данные с уменьшенного. И прописываем его в fstab как новый home. уменьшенный раздел удаляем.

Удаляем раздел root и создаем новый с освободившимся местом.

Увеличиваем размер файловой системы.

```
resize2fs /dev/md3
```

Не фс, а раид. /dev/md* это раид. Если вы не знаете что у вас там то скорее всего LVM. И это хорошо. Можно перекинуть место просто через lvresize и resize2fs

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: тип раида напиши какой у тебя там. подскажу подробнее

Comment: в обоих случаях ext4

Comment: Не фс, а раид. /dev/md* это раид. Если вы не знаете что у вас там то скорее всего LVM. И это хорошо. Можно перекинуть место просто через lvresize и resize2fs