# Как перераспределить дисковое пространство на виртуальном сервере centos?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Арендую сервер. А тут вот какая ситуация - на систему выделено 10гб памяти, за то на папку с сайтами 150гб.
[image: df -h]

Из-за этого появляется куча ошибок, база данных yum вся сломана и т.д.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли выйти как-то с этой ситуации? Хотелось бы перераспределить пространство, или просто смонтировать /dev/vdb в корень /

Comment: Я бы для начала разобрался, что занимает столько места. По моему опыту 10 гигов на систему более чем достаточно.

Comment: Если отвечать на ваш вопрос в лоб, то ответ: пишите хостеру. Вряд ли вы сможете изменить размер системного раздела "изнутри".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583657/178576 // прозреваю, что кто-то перепутал место назначения для файлов сайта: вместо /var/www/блабла они были скопированы в какое-то другое место в корневой файловой системе.

Comment: ¿А кто их так криво распределил изначально? У вам там еще и русская локализация кажется стоит.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так сайты еще не загружались вовсе. там практически пустая директория с ними, не считая стандартного приветственного шаблона html

Comment: @user7860670 ну вот я купил сервер, выбрал centos и мне выдали доступы. успел лишь установить nano

Comment: ¿И что, там прям с ходу было забито 10 гигов корневого раздела? Объем конечно маловат, но обычно же систему клиенту дают в минимальной установке. Что в /var/www/ что-то примонтировано - тоже странно.

Comment: @user7860670 там установлена ispmanager, плюс я установил nano и еще пару программ для удобства. а в var/www примонтирован как раз диск на который надо загружать сайты. я с подержкой связался, они просто папку media перенесли в /var/www, а в корень вынесли ссылку на нее. lol